# Android Studio: Could not initialize class com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.jar

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio. In event log it shows me:

```
5:38:38 PM NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.jar.JarHandler$CacheLibraryInfo: Could not initialize class com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.jar.JarHandler$CacheLibraryInfo
```

And say suppose I have registration.xml file is there in layout folder. so when i open it there are two tabs "Text" and "Design". If i want to write any property of ImageView then ctrl + space can not open property window.

What's happen I can't understand! Is it something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade Android Studio recently? We sometimes see problems with corrupted updates that manifest in ways similar to this; I'd try doing a fresh reinstall.

Comment: I don't know. But how can i check that? Is there any revert back option?

Comment: I started getting similar issue out of nowhere. A moment ago it was working fine and then got same crash issue. Tried validate and restart, closed and  started again, even created new project and its still the same. I am using studio 2.1.1.